# Spring. Saving pdf to disk location

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

In order to download PDF on disk

```xml
<bean id="pdfReport"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
        p:url="classpath:tree-template.jrxml"
        p:reportDataKey="datasource" 
        p:subReportUrls-ref="customSubReportUrls"
        p:subReportDataKeys-ref="customSubReportDatasource"
        p:exporterParameters-ref="exporterParameters"/>

    <util:map id="exporterParameters">
      <entry key="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME" value="c://tmp//asd.pdf"/>      
</util:map>
```

am specifying the above in *jasper-views.xml* file but my pdf is generating but not getting saved into classpath or the path i have specified.

Am I wrong in specifying *jasper-views.xml* file?

Answer (score 0):

The `exporterParameters`-ref is set wrong,

Change from

```
p:exporterParameters-ref="exporterParam`enter code here`eters"
```

to

```
p:exporterParameters-ref="exporterParameters"
```

Comment: i have  set it as p:exporterParameters-ref="exporterParameters" still pdf not getting saved